# how to prevent any update to my database before a exp operation?

Tags: oracle

I want to migrate my database from AIX to Red Hat vai exp/imp.

how to prevent clients make any update to my database during the migration progress ?

Comment: Stop the listener or put database in restricted mode. Of course you have to kill existing sessions after that. Also disable and kill jobs because they too can make changes to the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line

- from the command line enter lsnrctl and then stop (stops the listener, only connections from the server possible)
- connect to sqlplus as sysdba
- shutdown immediate  ( makes sure all sessions are terminated)
- startup restrict  (only allows users with dba privilege to log on)
- as Mindaugas Riauba mentions disable all jobs likely to change data during the export
- export your data
- alter system disable restricted session
- back to command line enter lsnrctl and start

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply lock the account used by your user

```
ALTER USER username ACCOUNT LOCK;
```

Comment: well you could do that for every user except SYS, SYSDBA but then existing sessions would still continue to run and someone could still log on who was in the ORA_DBA group (windows OS) and connect as sys, and jobs would still run..